# wordpress does not give 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress

**Hello all!**

I want to know that when **we click on menu item in wordpress website**, It takes us to the url associated with that link but how wordpress does that! I mean, the following url :

> http://www.example.com/this-is-another-page/

I know wordpress will get the data from database but **How wordpress will handle this url** because the page is not available **it should give 404 error**

please tell me.
I am learning php.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress handle this page by checking few things.

1. WP Check the credential by POST ID
2. First it's check the POST Exists or not? If not published then it gives you the 404 error.
3. WP check whether the post is published or not? If not published then it gives you the 404 error.

Then it's render the information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a link that page link is added in the database. If the page is not created and you put a link that not exist, wordpress will bring you up a page error template.